# Merge arrays on one column, sum other column values in each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = [
    ['amount' => 21600.00, 'rows' => 2, 'student_id' => 1],
];

$array2 = [
    ['amount' => 541990.00, 'rows' => 512, 'student_id' => 1],
    ['amount' => 347480.00, 'rows' => 281, 'student_id' => 2],
    ['amount' => 507400.00, 'rows' => 214, 'student_id' => 3],
];
```

I want to merge both arrays based on the same `student_id` value. When a `student_id` is found in both arrays, I want to sum the two `amount` values and the two `rows` values.

Expected result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'amount' => 563590.0,
    'rows' => 514,
    'student_id' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'amount' => 347480.0,
    'rows' => 281,
    'student_id' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'amount' => 507400.0,
    'rows' => 214,
    'student_id' => 3,
  ),
)
```

I have tried using `array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()` but they didn't give me the expected result.

Comment: i would just use a foreach() loop

Comment: Why you have this 2 array with the same similarity structure ? are you selecting it from two different table ? i think you should do this in database level.

Comment: Yes, I know but I can't do it via query. So I should do it via PHP. Btw I got the answer now from Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple code to solve your problem,

```
count($arr) > count($arr0) ? ($greater = $arr AND $smaller = $arr0) : ($smaller = $arr AND $greater = $arr0);
foreach ($greater as $key => &$value) {
    foreach ($smaller as $key1 => &$value1) {
        if($value['student_id'] == $value1['student_id']){
            $value['amount'] +=$value1['amount'];
            $value['rows'] +=$value1['rows'];
        }
    }
}
```

Check output [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf0cfbd2d424a9836571d215efa01f8236b3fd3a)

Answer (score 0):

The comment about combining the queries is probably the better approach.

```
SELECT student_id, sum(amount) as amount, sum(rows) as rows 
from students
group by student_id;
```

However, if you can't do it via a query, PHP doesn't natively add array values together (it doesn't make sense)

Here's what you'd have to do

```
function arrayMergeMatch(&$a, &$b)
{
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $b)) {
            // there's a matching index in both a & b
            $a[$key] = [
                $a[$key]['amount'] += $b[$key]['amount'],
                $a[$key]['rows'] += $b[$key]['rows'],
                $a[$key]['student_id'],
            ];
        }
    }
}

$firstArray = $secondArray = [];

$firstArray[0] = [
    'amount' => 21600.00,
    'rows'   => 2,
    'student_id' => 1 
];


$secondArray[0] = [
    'amount' => 541990.00,
    'rows' => 512,
    'student_id' => 1,
];

$secondArray[1] = [
    'amount' => 347480.00,
    'rows' => 281,
    'student_id' => 2,
];

$secondArray[2] = [
    'amount' => 507400.00,
    'rows' => 214,
    'student_id' => 3,
];

$firstArrayLength  = count($x);
$secondArrayLength = count($y);

$combinedArray = null;

if ($firstArrayLength > $secondArrayLength) {
    // loop through x checking to see if there's a matching y
    arrayMergeMatch($firstArray, $secondArray);
    $combinedArray = $firstArray;
}
else {
    // y is longer than or equal to x, so loop through y, looking for matching
    // index in x
    arrayMergeMatch($secondArray, $firstArray);
    $combinedArray = $secondArray;
}

print_r($combinedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops are not necessary.  There will be several different styles, but the crux of the task is to create a result array that temporarily serves as a lookup array while you iterate the incoming data.

To do this, assign temporary keys using `student_id` values.  When a `student_id` is encountered after it is found in the result array, just add the values to the stored related values in the group. When finished iterating, re-index the result with `array_values()`.

Functional style: ([Demo1](https://3v4l.org/NYJTj)) ([Demo2 - likely slower](https://3v4l.org/bGSc1))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $array2,
            function($result, $row) {
                if (!isset($result[$row['student_id']])) {
                    $result[$row['student_id']] = $row;
                } else {
                    $result[$row['student_id']]['amount'] += $row['amount'];
                    $result[$row['student_id']]['rows'] += $row['rows'];
                }
                return $result;
            },
            array_column($array1, null, 'student_id')
        )
    )
);
```

Language construct loop: ([Demo1](https://3v4l.org/c7Pc1)) ([Demo2 - likely slower](https://3v4l.org/ZvIeK))

```
$result = array_column($array1, null, 'student_id');
foreach ($array2 as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['student_id']])) {
        $result[$row['student_id']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['student_id']]['amount'] += $row['amount'];
        $result[$row['student_id']]['rows'] += $row['rows'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

All of the above snippets should be used instead of the other posted answers because they will never iterate more than `m + n`.  Here's a critique of the other answers:

- Rahul's answer is using a nested loop -- this means the number of iterations will be `m*n` (number of rows in array1 multiplied by number of rows in array2) -- this is very indirect/inefficient. Even if a `break` was used, it still wouldn't be as direct/efficient as my snippets.
- Kearney's answer is completely ignoring the requirement to sort on `student_id` values (even after the `$x` and `$y` typos are fixed).  This php-based answer is **simply incorrect**.  [Proof.](https://3v4l.org/WE9ja) Less importantly, `$b` does not need to be made modifiable by reference.